# How can i execute a .bat file using the relative path to it, on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I mean, if i'm in the folder foo, and within it there's another folder called bar, and whithin bar folder, there's a file.bat. 
In this scenario, i can't just type foo/bar/file.bat. I have to type the entire path to get the file executed, i.e (c:/foo/bar/file.bat).

Is there a way i can do just foo/bar/file.bat and execute the file.bat, without having to type the entire path to the file.bat?

P.S: I'm talking about Windows Command Prompt.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example code has forwards slashes instead of backward slashes (if you didn't notice).

Yes, if you are in foo with command prompt you can run `bar\file.bat` to open that batch script. You would not run as you say " `foo\bar\file.bat` " because you are already in foo, as you have said. But if you are in a different node (i.e C:\foo\john) and want to access bar\file.bat you must run `..\bar\file.bat`

If you want to navigate to any folder you may run `cd [nextfoldernodename]`. For example if you are in C: you may run `cd foo` to get in the foo folder, or if you type `cd foo\bar` you can get in the bar folder. (cd stands for **c**hange **d**irectory).

Comment: But  i want execute the file without having to move into its containing folder.

Comment: I solved it. I just had to type .\path\to\mybat.bat  Anyway, thank you for your support.

Comment: @inovapixel, you shouldn't require that .\ in order to access it though, is it not working without it? Because usually that is an additional symbol (unnecessary) to access the folder you are in. In CMD it should be unnecessary.

Comment: No, it's not. I tried /path/file.bat, \path\file.bat and it only worked with the . before the rest of the path

Comment: @inovapixel, does it work without the slashes at the beginning of the command line?

Comment: No. The . (dot) indicates that the path is the current folder + what comes forward it. Ex: .\folder\file.bat is equivalent to C:\folder\file.bat.

Comment: I understand what the period means and the slash (directory), but I am saying it is unnecessary to use the .\ if you are trying to access a folder that
 is in another node below it, for instance you don't have to do .\bar\file.bat (though you can) you can also do bar\file.bat without the .\ preceding it.

Comment: Oh, i got it! I really haven't tried this way. Thank you!